# Iphone OpenGL : gluLookAt X,Z to rotation (360) : Heading angle

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, glu

The OpenGL program I am writing uses a port of glULookat to control the camera

To rotate I have the following code

```
case ActionTurnLeft: 
center[0] = eye[0] + cos(-SPEED_TURN)*v[0] - sin(-SPEED_TURN)*v[2]; 
center[2] = eye[2] + sin(-SPEED_TURN)*v[0] + cos(-SPEED_TURN)*v[2]; 


break;
```

case ActionTurnRight: 
    center[0] = eye[0] + cos(SPEED_TURN)*v[0] - sin(SPEED_TURN)*v[2];
    center[2] = eye[2] + sin(SPEED_TURN)*v[0] + cos(SPEED_TURN)*v[2];

My question is how do I get the rotation angle in degrees?

Updated :  Tried this and it gave me -572 ish to 572

```
float rotAngleDegs;
float PI = 3.1415926535897;
rotAngleDegs = (cos(-SPEED_TURN)*v[0] - sin(-SPEED_TURN)*v[2]) * 180 / PI;
NSLog(@"%f", rotAngleDegs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incrementing a float by rotation +=2.865; seemed to actually work lol

Answer (score 1):

To get an angle in degrees just multiply the angle in radians by 180 / PI where PI = 3.1415926535897. In this case, the rotation angle in radians is the entire piece of code after eye[] part.

rotAngleDegs = (cos(-SPEED_TURN)*v[0] - sin(-SPEED_TURN)*v[2]) * 180 / PI

Comment: This produce very odd angles, did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a rotation matrix. [Wikipedia Rotation Matrix entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

-SPEED_TURN is the angle of rotation in radians which can be converted to degrees by multiplying the factor 180 / PI.

Comment: Speed_turn is a fixed value  e.g #define SPEED_TURN 0.05

Comment: Each time ActionTurnLeft is applied then the rotation will change by 0.05 * 180 / PI.  Which rotation angle are you trying to find?

Comment: Hi Doug  I want the rotation angle of the camera rotation which goes from 0 to 360 degrees.  Quite new to the whole OpenGL stuff.  Actually going to use this to work out which item I clicked on as no one seems to know how to work that out for me.  See last 2 posts

Comment: So would you say that an update to your question is that you want to know the heading angle the the eye is looking.  You could calculate the vector from the eye coordinate to the center coordinate and then determine the angle from there.

Comment: Sorry, no code samples.  Try searching for "vector angle", "dot product" and "cross product"